# Strikeout in CheckBox in To-Do List C#

Tags: c#, list, checkbox, strikethrough

I am trying to do "To-Do List" and when I mark something as checked to make the text strikeout:

```
        if (check.Checked)
        {
            check.Font = new Font(check.Font, FontStyle.Strikeout);
        }
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: It is not working, it doesn't make it strikeout, and it is not writing an error or something like that.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint, does it actually execute your code?

Comment: check.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;