# How to strikeout a text if item is checked in List?

Tags: c#, strikethrough, checklistbox

If you were to make a CheckedListBox with these functions:

1. Can't check more than 1 item at a time.
2. if Checked, strikout the text.(Kinda of like a To-Do List)
3. Make the checker green if possible?

For these 3 things I have no idea how to write the code.

I have looked at a question that really didn't have a proper answer. [Strikeout in CheckBox in To-Do List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465123/strikeout-in-checkbox-in-to-do-list-c-sharp).

I can only show what I have done so far...

```
private void PersonListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PersonListBox.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (PersonListBox.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            //Code to make item text strikout
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: last time I did something like that you had to do the drawing of the content yourself, then you can do colours, pictures whatever you like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change / set checkedListBox item fore colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588322/how-to-dynamically-change-set-checkedlistbox-item-fore-colour)

Answer (score 0):

if the item is checked you can do a line through the text using CSS

```
text-decoration: line-through;
```

to only allow one checkbox to be selected you could group the checkboxes and then use javascript/jquery to only allow one to be selected at a time to work like radio buttons.

you can also change the colour of the check box using css depending on how you want it to be styled but you can play around with this for youre preference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to coding. All I know is C#, and not much of it. Sorry.

Comment: ah right i dont think you will be able to do what you are looking for completely in c# is it a windows or web based applicaiton you are working on?

Comment: Windows forms application  

Comment: inside your if statement if you use somthing like:

PersonListBox.CheckedItems.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;

this should change the font text when it is checked.


as for the only selecting one checkbox item can you not use radio buttons instead of checkboxes as these have the default behavior of only selecting one

Comment: These two errors came up...

1. 'CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'TextDecorations' and no accessible extension method 'TextDecorations'....

2. The name 'TextDecorations' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I think I have found another way of dealing with it. But the problem now is that all the text in List get a strikeout and not only the checked item.

PersonListBox.Font = new Font(PersonListBox.Font.FontFamily, PersonListBox.Font.Size, FontStyle.Strikeout);

Comment: so with the code you have added is targetting the whole list. is there an option to target PersonListBox.CheckedItems.Font.FontFamily etc as you have already

Comment: Can't make it to work for a single item.... I guess I have to research and solve it myself. I'll answer my own question if I find the answer.

Comment: @AllanJ Wondered if you ever sorted out this issue